# Размещение ромбов на странице

Tags: html, css, design

Здравствуйте ! Нам нужно разместить ромбы на главной странице сайта, как на картинке. Как это лучше сделать ? Попробовали несколько способов, но все равно получается каша...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, как это выглядит сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где ваш код? Добавьте в вопрос его.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так. Изображения вставите, размеры выставите.

```css
#main {
  width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
.big {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
.big.big2 {
  left: 224px;
}
.big.big3 {
  left: 448px;
}
.group {
  position: relative;
}
.group.group0 {
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.group.group1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 112px;
}
.group.group2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 335px;
}
.group.group3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 107px;
  left: 335px;
}
.group.group3 .small3 {
  top: 111px;
}
.group.group3 .small1 {
  top: 111px;
}
.group.group4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 107px;
  left: 112px;
}
.group.group4 .small3 {
  top: 111px;
}
.group.group4 .small1 {
  top: 111px;
}
.small {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  margin: 10px;
}
.small.small2 {
  top: 55px;
  left: 55px;
}
.small.small3 {
  left: 110px;
}
/* Center the demo */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="group group0">
    <div class="big big1"></div>
    <div class="big big2"></div>
    <div class="big big3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group1">
    <div class="small small1"></div>
    <div class="small small2"></div>
    <div class="small small3"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="group group2">
    <div class="small small1"></div>
    <div class="small small2"></div>
    <div class="small small3"></div> 
  </div>
   <div class="group group3">
    <div class="small small1"></div>
    <div class="small small2"></div>
    <div class="small small3"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="group group4">
    <div class="small small1"></div>
    <div class="small small2"></div>
    <div class="small small3"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/dezzignet/pen/pRLbOv

Comment: firefox - не работает